# Room database not considering a type converter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have an Entity class like this

```
@Entity
data class NewsResponse(
        @PrimaryKey
        @field:SerializedName("news")
        val news: ArrayList<NewsItem?>? = null
)
```

The NewsItem class is like this

```
@Entity
data class NewsItem(

    @field:SerializedName("imgUrl")
    val imgUrl: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("link")
    val link: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("description")
    val description: String? = null,

    @PrimaryKey
    @field:SerializedName("title")
    val title: String? = null
)
```

Then I have DAO for NewsResponse like this

```
@Dao
interface NewsRespDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM NewsItem")
    fun getNewsItems():LiveData<List<NewsItem>>

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    fun insertNews(newsList: List<NewsItem?>?)

    @Query("DELETE FROM NewsItem")
    fun deleteAll()
}
```

I also have a TypeConverter defined like this

```
class NewsConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromString(value:String):ArrayList<NewsItem>{
        val listType = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<NewsItem>>() {

        }.type
        return Gson().fromJson(value, listType)
    }

    fun fromArrayList(list:ArrayList<NewsItem>):String{
        val gson = Gson()
        return gson.toJson(list)
    }
}
```

Then in RoomDatabase class I have defined the TypeConverter annotation like this

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Source::class,NewsResponse::class),version = 1)
@TypeConverters(NewsConverter::class)
abstract class SourceDataBase : RoomDatabase(){
    abstract fun sourceDao():SourceDao

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE:SourceDataBase?=null

        fun getInstance(context: Context):SourceDataBase?{
            if(INSTANCE == null){
                synchronized(SourceDataBase::class){
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,SourceDataBase::class.java,"source.db")
                            .build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE
        }
        fun destroyInstance(){
            INSTANCE=null
        }

    }


}
```

But whenever I try to run, I get an error saying

```
Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
```

To save a List of objects one of the way is by defining TypeConverter and I have defined it but still I am getting the error. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a NewsConverter. You do not need a NewsResponse as Entity. 
your entities must be like this:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Source::class,NewsItem::class),version = 1)
abstract class SourceDataBase : RoomDatabase(){
```

and then everything should be work fine

Comment: and ArrayList cann't be a PrimaryKey

Comment: yes you're right. Seems like what OP is trying to do is counterintuitive. Room already knows how to put an object in a list, no need for a converter.